# Splitting a string for CSV formatting

Tags: javascript, csv, split

I have a string that I've formed based on certain data. It contains a list of comma separated values.

I run this string through a function which allows me to separate these values so that I can show them appropriately in the HTML.

This works fine. However there's one error I'm unable to resolve. One of the returned values is from a HTML textfield which means the user can write on multiple different lines. As a result, the function I use to split up my values is splitting up the textfield values into multiple lines.

I've consoled logged my string before it hits the function. As you can see, the comments appear fine in the quotations with a space in between.

```
20,Order,Item,Title,,Assignee,Comments,Image Path,Timestamp,Due Date,Completed
21,0,1,"Issue 1",,"","I have some comments that are 

going here on multiple lines",,"2019/11/28, 12:20:55","",""
```

The function

```
  csvToJSON(csv) {

    const lines: string[] = csv
      // escape everything inside quotes to NOT remove the comma there
      .replace(/"(.*?)"/gm, (item) => encodeURIComponent(item))
      .split('\n');

    lines.pop();

    // separate the headers from the other lines and split them
    const headers: string[] = lines.shift().split(',');

    // should contain all CSV lines parsed for the html table
    const data: any[] = lines.map((lineString, index) => {
      const lineObj = {};

      const lineValues = lineString.split(',');

      headers.forEach((valueName, index) => {
        // remove trailing spaces and quotes
        if (lineValues[index] != undefined) {
          lineObj[valueName] = lineValues[index].replace(/%22(.*?)%22/gm, (item) => decodeURIComponent(item)).trim();
        }
      });

      return lineObj; // return lineObj for objects.
    });

    console.log('csvToJSON - data = ', data);

    return { data, headers };
  }
```

In the above function, you can see a console log at the end to log the final converted data.

This ends up resulting in the following:

```
0: {20: "21", Order: "0", Item: "1", Title: ""Issue 1"", "": "", Assignee: """", …}
1: {20: ""}
2: {20: "going here on multiple lines",,"2019/11/28", Order: "12:20:55","","""}
```

As you can see, my comments have been a bit butchered.

Is there a way to resolve this so that everything else is separated correctly, but my comments text (which can have multiple lines) isn't broken up?

Comment: how are `"` encodes if someone would write `the item is "available" on request``  in the csv? Will it be double `""` quoted as escape?

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
function CSVtoArray(text) {
         var re_valid =  /^\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|[^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*)\s*(?:,\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|[^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*)\s*)*$/;
         var re_value =  /(?!\s*$)\s*(?:'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"|([^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*))\s*(?:,|$)/g;
        if (!re_valid.test(text)) return null;
        var a = [];                    
        text.replace(re_value,
            function(m0, m1, m2, m3) {
                if      (m1 !== undefined) a.push(m1.split("|");
                else if (m2 !== undefined) a.push(m2.split(","));
                else if (m3 !== undefined) a.push(m3);
                return ''; 
            });
        if (/,\s*$/.test(text)) a.push('');
        return a;
    };
```

Comment: This is amazingly close. Thank you. The remaining issue here is that if you take a look at the first snippet in my post, there's a new line after `completed`. That first line acts as the CSV headers, the next line is the data associated with those headers. Your code resolves the comments issue, but now puts everything onto one long line. Additionally, the `completed` text now appears as `Completed 21` (21 should be the start of the new line) The html I used was the following: <li *ngFor="let test of data">
{{test}}</li>